# Is every non-set collection just a collection of "sets with some extra data"?

Tags: set-theory, type-theory

Okay, so in set theory, all the sets together do not form a set, so we say we have a "class" of sets (for example, if we do category theory). In the same way, we have a class of groups, topological spaces, graphs etc. All of these things are based on sets. (Even better: these classes contain at least one element per set, for example a space with the discrete topology, or a fully connected graph).

In the same way (as far as I understand it), in type theory, we (can) have universes, let's call them $ U_1 $ (equivalent to SET), $ U_1: U_2 $, $ U_2: U_3 $ etc. We can also take $ U_n \subseteq U_{n + 1} $ if we want.

Now, what things live in $ U_2 \setminus U_1 $? Are all of these "the collection of elements of $ U_1 $, together with some data" (or perhaps "the collection of tuples of elements of $ U_1 $, together with some data", e.g. morphisms between sets)? Or are there also new, wild, "atomic" things there?

EDIT: let me try to clarify my question a bit: $ SET $ cannot not an element of $ SET $ (because we would run into paradoxes then). In the same way, $ \{ SET(a, b) | a, b \in SET\} $ (the collection of set functions) or $ Grp $ (the collection of groups) or $ Top $ the collection of topological spaces, cannot be elements of $ SET $, because they are "too big": there is a surjection from them onto $ SET $, because their elements (topological spaces, groups, ...) are "a set, together with some data". Now, my question is: are all the things that are "too big" for $ SET $, but can live in a higher universe, of this form?

I know that you can formally (synthetically) adjoin things (like urelements) to the higher universe, but we can just as well adjoin them to $ SET $ then, right?

Comment: Yes, in set theory we may have "atomic" objects, i.e. individuals that are not collections. See [urelement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement).

Comment: Right. Urelements feel a bit synthetic? Like formally added elements? But are there also things (that are not [big because they contain a lot of sets]) living in these higher universes by necessity, because they do not fit in the lower universes?

Comment: My understanding, as a set theorist, is that the idea behind universes is to allow us to apply set theoretic tools to proper classes. Namely, we want to collect them, discuss collections of their collections, recursively define all manner of things, etc. So, it helps if the universe we started with is merely a small object in a larger one. And you want to do that, repeatedly, so you'd normally just assume there are a lot of these universes, so that you never really run out.

Comment: Mathematics has from its beginnings to now always dealt with many objects that we would prefer not think of as sets, such as points and numbers. There is nothing "synthetic" about considering a set theory that allows us to discuss them without requiring them to be sets. Set theory generally doesn't do this simply because it simplifies the set theory itself to not include urelements - for example in the ability to actually define equality rather than treating it as a primitive.